# Dynamically changing column name

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I am using `rad:radgrid` datagrid control. I need to change column header text dynamically.

I try `rgGrid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Id"` and it works fine for `GridBoundColumn`, but now I need to do the same for `GridButtonColumn` but it not working

I also try:

```
<rad:GridButtonColumn HeaderText="<%= stringText %>" >
```

but it doesn't work becouse rad controls does not allowed to use <% %>.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this ASP.NET?  Please tag as appropriate - C# isn't specific enough to be obvious in this case.

Comment: see this may be helpful to you http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/change-name-of-column-in-radgrid-column-name-is-item.aspx   `protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (e.Item is GridHeaderItem) 
        { 
            GridHeaderItem headerItem = (GridHeaderItem)e.Item; 
            headerItem.Cells[2].Text = "CustomHeader"; 
        } 
    } `

Comment: @WaqarJanjua your answer above is exactly what I was looking for, it helped me solve an issue I spent a whole day struggling to solve. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but since all WebControls allow setting an ID and then call the control by the ID, you can:

```
<rad:GridButtonColumn ID="MyGridButtonColumn">
```

and then in the CodeBehind:

```
MyGridButtonColumn.MyHeaderText = stringText;
```